# Using hashmap in different Class

Tags: java, hashmap

In class **manager** I have couple methods that are using HashMap so adding deleting etc.

class **Manager**

```
HashMap<String, User> UserMap = new HashMap<String, User>();
//methods here to manage the User values.
```

class **Interface**

I want to get the instance of this hashmap. 
Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: "Interface" is probably not the best name for a class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please dont use `Interface` as classname.

```
public class Manager {
   private HashMap<String, User> UserMap = new HashMap<String, User>();



    public HashMap<String, User> getUserMap() {
        return UserMap;
    }

    public void setUserMap(HashMap<String, User> UserMap) {
        this.UserMap = UserMap;
    }

   // other operations

}

public class Interface{
    private HashMap<String, User> UserMap =null;


    public void setUserMap(HashMap<String, User> UserMap) {
        this.UserMap = UserMap;
    }

}


public class AnotherClass{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
               AnotherClass anotherClassObj= new AnotherClass();
               anotherClassObj.go();
    }
  public void go(){

    Manager obj1=new Manager();
    ///obj1 operations
    Interface obj2=new Interface();
    obj2.setUserMap(obj1.getUserMap());
   //obj2 operations

   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you man :) 
I needed to get the only values from hashmap so i used only the getUserMap() but thank you :)